# How to form a time series in R using a sin equation?

Tags: r

I need help forming a time series for t=1,...,200 where x(t)=sin(t*pi/50) and then plotting it.

It seems like I need to create a vector but I'm not sure how to do this without typing each component out.

This is what I have so far, obviously not right.

```
for (i in 1:200) { v<- sin(i*pi/50)}
```

Comment: Try `t = 1:200` to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
v <- numeric(200)  ## allocate space for the vector
for (i in 1:200) { v[i] <- sin(i*pi/50)}
```

although, since R does vectorized computations, `t <- 1:200; v <- sin(t*pi/50)` would be better.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful! I'm also struggling with converting to the time series to plot. I'm pretty sure I need to use ts() and then plot that but I can't seem to get the syntax right, any tips?

Comment: don't bother with `ts()`.  Just use `plot(t,v)`.